# Is there any mechanism to use more than one GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in codebase?

Tags: dialogflow-es

we are having more than one project in one google service account and each project is having separate `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` json file. As per requirement based on locale and `projectID` we have to use relevant credential json file.

Tried loading through environment variable but that can accept only one file path,

Set environment variable

```sh
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/[FILE_NAME].json"
```

expect authentication success if request is coming from any project with in that service account.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set credentials from json file directly instead of setting it in the environment variable.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = "/home/user/Downloads/[FILE_NAME].json"
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE)
project_id = "project_id"
session_id = "session_id"
session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient(credentials=credentials)
session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
// 1. read json by InputStream
    InputStream stream = context.getAssets().open("-----.json");
    GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(stream);
    String projectId = ((ServiceAccountCredentials)credentials).getProjectId();

// 2. build SessionSettings
    SessionsSettings.Builder settingsBuilder = SessionsSettings.newBuilder();
    SessionsSettings sessionsSettings = settingsBuilder.setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials)).build();

// 3. create SessionsClient
    SessionsClient sessionsClient = SessionsClient.create(sessionsSettings)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check  "-----.json" file.

There are private_key and client_email.

You can use them in code.
This works fine.

```
let config = {
    credentials: {
        private_key: private_key,
        client_email: client_email
    }
};


// Create a new session
const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient(config);
const sessionPath = sessionClient.projectAgentSessionPath(
  projectId,
  sessionId
);
```

This will be helpful.